# Angular directive for hiding an element for printing

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to add print functionality to a webapp using Angular 2. I would like some elements and components to show only when printing, and others only when not printing.

I believe this can be done using CSS `@media` queries, however it may be more elegant to do this with Angular directives.

I would like to do something like the following

```html
<div *appPrint="false" class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <app-print-page></app-print-page>
  </div>
</div>
<div *appPrint="true" class="row">
  <app-print-header></app-print-header>
</div>
```

Is this possible, or should I switch to media queries?

Comment: I think it would probably be simpler with media queries to be honest. Just create  a `noprint` CSS class and add it to anything you dont want to print

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this situation i tackled it in different way.

1. Add a new button to screen , click on the button a new page will loaded in the next tab with a different view with different widget and data. the from there taking the print.

Bringing all the information which needed for the print to normal page load will may affect the performance. in my case the normal page is loaded with graphs and widget by when user printing the need real data in tabular format.

If you only want to hide few information from the existing page then **@media query** will be the best option.

```
media="screen, print"
```